# Adding files when installing a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I'm writing a gem which needs a directory to store some config. I want to do this upon installation but I'm not sure how best to insert code into the installation process.

By adding the code to the `Rakefile` and adding `spec.extensions = ["Rakefile"]` to my gemspec, I've achieved what I want to do but this method means the installation process tells me I'm building native extensions; this is misleading.

Is there a built in way of doing this or via bundler? I'm assuming `Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks` is close to what I'm after but I can't find helpful documentation.

EDIT: My current [Rakefile](http://pastebin.com/rCrLfk74).

Comment: Can we get some example snips of what you're doing now?  Not sure if you're creating files, directories, copying existing data, what...

Comment: @NickVeys Edited in a link.

Comment: To be honest, I'd make that something the application itself generates on its first run.  I imagine it's fairly quick?

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense in this context I guess. In general though, is there an accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the RubyGems designers intentionally left the option to run a script during installation... so I would say that the accepted way is to do the directory creation in the application.

The unix way is for the application to create the directory (vi and git do this).

FileUtils.mkdir_p is handy... it will save you from having to check if the directory is already there.